# laravel query with closure

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to query database and make a filter in a closure function, my model (Simplified) looks like this:

```
Products:
    id,
    sale_id

Sales:
    id,
    provider_id

Provider:
    id
```

I wanna all the products from a specific provider, so i've constructed this my query:

```
Product::with(array
           ('sale'=>function($query){
                $query->where('provider_id', '=', 1);
            })
        )->get();
```

the problem is that the result contains the right products with the sale, and the wrong products with the sale null, like this:

```
[{
    "id": 25,
    "sale": null
},
{
    "id": 26,
    "sale": {
        "id": 15,
        "provider_id": 3
    }
}]
```

products with sale:null are the products from another provider, I could filter them in memory, but I think there is a way to avoid the null results from the query, any clue?

Comment: what are you trying to do with so:  products with sale:null are the products from another provider

Comment: i was trying to return only the products from an specific provider, i did not want products from another provider at all (with or without sale: null).
The second comment of Adiaz solve my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add check about sale exists **whereHas('sale')** and apply condition about specific provider:

```
Product::whereHas('sale', function($query) { 
    $query->where('provider_id', '=', 1); }
)->get();
```

Comment: same result here, i asume that the "has(sale)" is checking if the product has any sale, not if the sale is the one with the provider_id

Comment: if my provider id is given by input(it can be multiple or single, how am I suppose to do it? Can you help?

Comment: Use whereIn method and map input to array  $query->whereIn('provider_id', (array) $inputArrayOrSingle );

Comment: sry, can you have a look on this question please?